# Shell Scripting array not printing proper values

Tags: bash

I have this simple Shell Script where I am searching for ID and Port Number from the file and saving it in Array.  However When I try to print them I am not getting expected results.  I am looping the array to print the 1st and 2nd element and then increasing by two to print 3rd and 4th element.  I also want to print them like each ID Port in separate line, like this:

```
ID Port
ID Port
```

My code is:

```
myarr=($(less radius-req | grep C4-3A-BE-18-C1-2D -B75 | grep '2018-11\|Port' | grep -v User | grep Source -B1 | awk -F "Port:|id=" '{print $2}' )); for ((i=0;i<"${#myarr[@]}";i+=2)) ; do echo $i; printf "%s\n"  "${myarr[$i]}"  "${myarr[$i+1]}"  ; done;
```

Even If I try to echo the whole array I only see the last element, whereas I could print each individual element without an issue.

```
$ myarr=($(less radius-req | grep C4-3A-BE-18-C1-2D -B75 | grep '2018-11\|Port' | grep -v User | grep Source -B1 | awk -F "Port:|id=" '{print $2}' )); echo ${myarr[@]}
 45210


$ myarr=($(less radius-req | grep C4-3A-BE-18-C1-2D -B75 | grep '2018-11\|Port' | grep -v User | grep Source -B1 | awk -F "Port:|id=" '{print $2}' )); echo ${myarr[0]}
19


$ myarr=($(less radius-req | grep C4-3A-BE-18-C1-2D -B75 | grep '2018-11\|Port' | grep -v User | grep Source -B1 | awk -F "Port:|id=" '{print $2}' )); echo ${myarr[1]}
45210


$ myarr=($(less radius-req | grep C4-3A-BE-18-C1-2D -B75 | grep '2018-11\|Port' | grep -v User | grep Source -B1 | awk -F "Port:|id=" '{print $2}' )); echo ${myarr[2]}
20


$ myarr=($(less radius-req | grep C4-3A-BE-18-C1-2D -B75 | grep '2018-11\|Port' | grep -v User | grep Source -B1 | awk -F "Port:|id=" '{print $2}' )); echo ${myarr[3]}
45210
```

Comment: It is hard to give advice without knowing what the input data looks like. Can you edit your question to include a portion of the input file?

Comment: `less` is a tool for interactively viewing data and should not be used to write data into a pipe.  For that, use `cat`.  (eg, `cat file | ...`).  But don't do that, either.  Instead, use a redirection.   Look up one of the roughly 77,800 result returned searching for "UUOC".

Comment: Not to mention, your entire string of pipelines ending in a call to `awk` can probably all be done in `awk` without spawning the multiple subshells.

Answer (score 1):

From the output you give, I suspect that the problem is due to carriage return characters in the radius-req file. My guess is the file is from Windows (or maybe a web download), which uses carriage return + linefeed as a line terminator. Unix uses just linefeed (aka newline) as a terminator, and unix programs will treat the carriage return as part of the content of the line. Net result: you get things like "`19<CR>`" and "`45210<CR>`" as array values, and when you print them it prints them all over top of each other.

If I'm right about the problem, it's pretty easy to fix. Just replace `less radius-req` (which you shouldn't use anyway, see William Pursell's comment) with `tr -d '\r' <radius-req`. The `tr` command does character replacements, `-d` means just delete instead of replacing, and `\r` is its notation for the carriage return character. Result: it deletes the carriage returns before they have a chance to mess things up.

Comment: Thank you removing carriage using  tr -d '\r' <radius-req helped